# Postgres User Authentication on web app through LoginRoles Vs Table

Tags: sql, security, postgresql, authentication

I have a postgres database and a web app.

The web app allows the existance of users and they do some stuff on the webapp.

I am new to postgres but what we used to do in SQL Server was ActiveDirectory - CreateLogins - CreateRoles etc..

Now in this database is it possible to create a login for each user? or is a table with users (username password) better? or worse?

I was thinking about having 1 login user in the database that can only do specific procedures and see views and just authenticate the user through the table.

Which is better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one or more [roles](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/user-manag.html) with specific permissions that access the login tables, along with the rest of the app's tables. You obviously don't want that role to be the database/table owner, to mitigate damage from an attack.

Be sure to use the [pgcrypto module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgcrypto.html) to salt and hash user passwords.

Comment: quick question, but how do you authenticate the user vs both username and passowrd? something like this will not work:
SELECT oid FROM pg_roles where rolname = 'blah' and rolpassword = 'blah' , also a bit of a dummy question havent used salt and hash yet, but if there are 2 same usernames will the output be different?

Comment: Database client authentication can be done many ways, so here's the [relevant documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/client-authentication.html). Salting makes the hashed values of two identical passwords different.

Comment: omg ye ofc. i was totally thinking about it the wrong way..(about the auth) thnx !

Comment: I just started implementing this and I was wondering wether I should hash and salt the password and username on the serverside prior to sending them for storage to the DB. Thanks!

Comment: Application-server-side encryption is fine. It just needs to be done on a trusted system. That said, I'd use pgcrypto, because it makes it so darn easy.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better to use the database's built-in role management, as it keeps it DRY. Despite myths, you can still use connection pooling. It makes it much easier to audit, and to use row-level security later if you need it.

1. Postgres can authenticate users using built-in roles, or using Kerberos, GSSAPI, SSPI or LDAP.
2. You can sync LDAP users/groups/roles with Postgres:

   https://github.com/larskanis/pg-ldap-sync
3. You can delegate authentication to the web server. Login as the web server role, and then change the user's role, to act as that user, using SET ROLE X. This lets you use connection pooling.